# How we can verify Email and SMS OTP at same time

Tags: python, django, web, twilio

I'm implementing 2FA with Twilio. I want to verify email and SMS OTP both at the same time.
If I send Email and SMS OTP if the User enters the wrong OTP one of the. The valid otp verifies but the other one is not. how we can achieve this to verify both at the same time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A verification via Twilio Verify is a verification for one factor at a time. I would recommend that you send out one verification, wait for the user to verify that factor, then send out the next verification over the other channel.